# how to merge 2 rows together WITH 2 rows in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, merge, html-table, swap

I am not so good in English, to express myself, so I show it with examples to you!

Here is my HTML table with code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr id="tr1_1">
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td>tr1.1 td2</td>
        <td>tr1.1 td3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="#" class="move up">up</a>/
            <a href="#" class="move down">down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr1_2">
        <td>tr1.2 td2</td>
        <td>td1.2 td3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="tr2_1">
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td>tr2.1 td2</td>
        <td>tr2.1 td3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="#" class="move up">up</a>/
            <a href="#" class="move down">down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2_2">
        <td>tr2.2 td2</td>
        <td>td2.2 td3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(You can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UQz8u/))

For example, if I click on the second two rows' "up" link, the result should be this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr id="tr2_1">
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td>tr2.1 td2</td>
        <td>tr2.1 td3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="#" class="move up">up</a>/
            <a href="#" class="move down">down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2_2">
        <td>tr2.2 td2</td>
        <td>td2.2 td3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="tr1_1">
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td>tr1.1 td2</td>
        <td>tr1.1 td3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="#" class="move up">up</a>/
            <a href="#" class="move down">down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr1_2">
        <td>tr1.2 td2</td>
        <td>td1.2 td3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(You can see the final result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/88NND/))

So how could I do this? I know the `prev()` and `before()` methods in javascript, but it merge only 1 row with 1 row, but I want to merge 2 rows WITH 2 rows!
I hope, someone can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this jQuery code :

```
$('.up').click(function() {
    tr = $('tr[id^="'+$(this).closest('tr').attr('id').slice(0, 3)+'"]')
    tr.insertBefore(tr.eq(0).prev().prev())
    return false;
})

$('.down').click(function() {
    tr = $('tr[id^="'+$(this).closest('tr').attr('id').slice(0, 3)+'"]')
    tr.insertAfter(tr.eq(1).next().next())
    return false;
})
```

And have a look to your fiddle edited : http://jsfiddle.net/lulu3030/UQz8u/6/

Just some explanations :

- `closest('tr')` method find the nearest parent which has a tr tag
- `slice(0, 3)` get the first 3 characters of a string
- => variable tr selects all elements which has the same 3 first id characters
- `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` methods allows to move selected elements

Comment: you are rock! i wish i could understand more than a half of your code :(

Comment: `tr = $('tr[id^="'+$(this).closest('tr').attr('id').slice(0, 3)+'"]')` this means, that the `tr` attribute will be the all `tr`, which IDs start with the same first 3 character? and the `tr.eq(1)` means --> the second row in the `tr` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Could be done like that too:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7pT4Z/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.up, .down').on('click', function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
            $flag = $('<tr/>').insertBefore($tr),
            $rows = $tr.add($tr.next('tr')).detach()
            methods = $(this).is('.up') ? ['insertBefore', 'prevAll'] : ['insertAfter', 'nextAll'];

        if ($flag[methods[1]]('tr').eq(1).length) {
            $rows[methods[0]]($flag[methods[1]]('tr').eq(1));
            $flag.remove();
        } else $flag.replaceWith($rows);
    });
});
```